# Strongly convex function and subgradient

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

I don't know how to prove the following statement:

> Let $x, x'$ arbitrary and $x^*\in\partial h(x)$. If $h$ is $\rho$-strongly convex, i.e,
> $$h(\lambda x + (1-\lambda)x')\leq \lambda h(x) + (1-\lambda)h(x') - \rho \frac{\lambda(1-\lambda)} 2\|x-x'\|^2,\quad \forall x,x', \quad \lambda\in(0,1),$$
> then:
> $$h(x)\ge h(x') + \left<x^*,x-x'\right> - \frac \rho 2 \|x-x'\|^2.$$

Answer (score 0):

I will assume that $x' \in \text{int}(\text{dom}(h))$ is an interior point of the domain of $h$.

If $h \colon E \to (- \infty, \infty]$ (which I assume to be proper, convex and lower semicontinuous, where $E$ is a real Banach space) is $\sigma$-strongly convex, then its subdifferential is $\sigma$-strongly convex, that is,
$$
\langle p_1 - p_0, x_1 - x_0 \rangle
\ge \sigma \| x_1 - x_0 \|^2 \qquad \forall p_k \in \partial h(x_k), \ k \in \{ 1, 2 \}.
$$
Without loss of generality we can assume that $h(x) < \infty$, otherwise the statement is obvious.
Consider the function $\varphi \colon \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$, $t \mapsto h\big( x_t \big)$, where $x_t := (1 - t) x' + t x$.
Note that $x_t \in \text{int}(\text{dom}(h))$ for all $t \in (0, 1)$.
We have $\partial \varphi(t) = \{ \langle p, x - x' \rangle: p \in \partial h(x_t) \}$ for $t \in (0, 1)$.

By the convex mean value theorem in integral form we have
$$
h(x) - h(x')
= \varphi(1) - \varphi(0)
= \int_{0}^{1} \langle s(t), x - x' \rangle \, \text{d}t,
$$
where $s \colon (0, 1) \to E^*$ is a selection of $\partial h$ along the line segment from $x'$ to $x$, that is, $s(t) \in \partial h(x_t)$ for all $t \in (0, 1)$.

The strong monotonicity of $\partial h$ yields
$$
\langle s(t) - s(0), x_t - x' \rangle
\ge \sigma \| x_t - x' \|^2
\qquad \forall t \in (0, 1).
$$
Hence
$$
\langle s(t), x - x' \rangle
\ge \langle s(0), x - x' \rangle + t \sigma \| x - x' \|^2
\qquad \forall t \in (0, 1).
$$
Hence
\begin{align*}
h(x) - h(x')
& = \int_{0}^{1} \langle s(t), x - x' \rangle \, \text{d}t
\ge \int_{0}^{1} \langle s(0), x - x' \rangle + t \sigma \| x - x' \|^2 \, \text{d}t \\
& = \langle s(0), x - x' \rangle + \frac{1}{2} \sigma \| x - x' \|^2.
\end{align*}